# Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Slighty new to django..
I got this error when attempting to do "django-admin makemigrations"

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must
>   either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Also get this error when attempting to load my home page:

> OperationalError at /home/ no such table: home_post

Answer (score 1):

You should use `manage.py`, not `django-admin`, to run management commands inside your project.